# My button on tkinter won't show despite using all sorts of techniques like pack, grid etc... I am trying to use an 'apply' button to set value

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I am trying to place a simple 'apply' button on my tkinter window in order to set the inputted value by the user to edit a fractal program I am producing through pygame. However, I have been stuck here for a very long time on such a simple problem. My button simply won't show. I am not sure if I am completely blind to this bug or it genuinely isn't a problem on my end? Any help would be much appreciated. Ignore the code in green - it's another part of the program I was working on haha.

```
def editingTk():
    global editWindow
    editWindow = Tk()
    editWindow.geometry("500x300")
    editWindow.title("Fractal Editing Window")

    editLabelTitle = Label(editWindow, text="Please input the values required", font = ("Calibri", 20)).place(x=50, y=3)

    global maximumIterationsInput
    global maxItEntry

    maximumIterationsInput = StringVar()
    labelMaxIt = Label(editWindow, text="Maximum Iterations", width = "25").place(x=27, y=130)
    requiredIterations = Label(editWindow, text="*", fg="red").place(x=335, y=130)
    maxItEntry = Entry(editWindow, textvariable = maximumIterationsInput).place(x=170, y=130)

    global maximumItEntry
    maximumItEntry = maximumIterationsInput.get()
    return maximumItEntry 
    '''
        self.dropOptions = [
             "300x350", 
             "500x500",
             "900x950",
             "1280x720",
             "1440x900",
             "1920x1080"
        ]
        
        self.sizeOptions = [
             [300, 500],
             [500, 500],
             [900, 950],
             [1280, 750],
             [1920, 1080]
        ]
        
        self.clicked = StringVar()
        self.clicked.set(self.sizeOptions[0])
        
        self.size300x500 = self.sizeOptions[0]
        self.size500x500 = self.sizeOptions[1]
        self.size900x950 = self.sizeOptions[2]
        self.size1280x720 = self.sizeOptions[3]
        self.size1920x1080 = self.sizeOptions[4]

        if self.clicked == "300x350":
            self.height = self.sizeOptions[0][0]
            self.width = self.sizeOptions[0][1]
        if self.clicked == "500x500":
            self.height = self.sizeOptions[1][0]
            self.width = self.sizeOptions[1][1]
        if self.clicked == "900x950":
            self.height = self.sizeOptions[2][0]
            self.width = self.sizeOptions[2][1]
        if self.clicked == "1280x720":
            self.height = self.sizeOptions[3][0]
            self.width = self.sizeOptions[3][1]
        if self.clicked == "1440x900":
            self.height = self.sizeOptions[4][0]
            self.width = self.sizeOptions[4][1]
        if self.clicked == "1920x1080":
            self.height = self.sizeOptions[5][0]
            self.width = self.sizeOptions[5][1]
    

        
        self.drop = OptionMenu(self.editWindow, self.clicked, *self.dropOptions)
        self.drop.pack()
        dropButton = Button(self.editWindow, text="Show screen sizes", command=self.show).pack()
     ''' 
    

    Button(editWindow, text="Apply", width=15, height=30, command = main(s, scale)).place(x=50, y = 150).pack()
    editWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Button` is called after `return`. So it'll never actually run. Try moving your `return` statement at the end of your function.

Comment: Why is there a bunch of code that is commented out with triple quotes? Also, are you aware that all code after `return` will never run?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the indent from the last 2 lines, or call the Defined function

Comment: You are not calling the function!!